# MySQL - Subtracting from separate queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The goal is to subtract query 1 from query 2 and display it in a table. I can handle the

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

portion of the request, but I can't get the following to work.  It is meant to take this months sales from last months to see where they stand in comparison.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT (
Select
    User, 
    SUM(COMPUTERS) as COMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) as LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) as PCCOMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits) as KEYBOARDSTotal, 
    SUM(MOUSEUnits) as MOUSETotal, 
    SUM(PRINTERSUnits) as PRINTERSTotal, 
    SUM(MISCUnits) as MISCTotal,
    SUM(PACKAGES) as PACKAGESTotal,
    (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as LAPTOPPercentage,
    (round(SUM(PACKAGES) / SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as PACKAGEPercentage,
    SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) as PERIPHERALTotal,
    round(SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS),2) as PERIPHERALPERSALE,
    ((SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * (SUM(COMPUTERS) * 1)) * (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2))) as Ratio
FROM my_db
WHERE YEAR(`Created`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(`Created`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)
-
(
Select
    User,   
    SUM(COMPUTERS) as COMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) as LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) as PCCOMPUTERSTotal,
    SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits) as KEYBOARDSTotal, 
    SUM(MOUSEUnits) as MOUSETotal, 
    SUM(PRINTERSUnits) as PRINTERSTotal, 
    SUM(MISCUnits) as MISCTotal, 
    SUM(PACKAGES) as PACKAGESTotal,
    (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as LAPTOPPercentage,
    (round(SUM(PACKAGES) / SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as PACKAGEPercentage,
    SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) as PERIPHERALTotal,
    round(SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS),2) as PERIPHERALPERSALE,
    ((SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * (SUM(COMPUTERS) * 1)) * (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2))) as Ratio
FROM my_db
WHERE `Created` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 1 DAY
)");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you missing `GROUP BY User` in your subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a row of data as a value in an expression. You can only use a subquery as a value if it returns a single element (1 row containing one column). For what you're doing, you need to join the subqueries and then subtract each column.

I think you're also missing `GROUP BY User` in your queries; it makes little sense to select that column if you're not calculating the totals by user.

```
SELECT lastmonth.User, 
       lastmonth.COMPUTERSTotal - lastday.COMPUTERSTotal AS COMPUTERSTotal,
       lastmonth.LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal - lastday.COMPUTERSTotal AS LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal,
       ...
FROM (Select
        User, 
        SUM(COMPUTERS) as COMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) as LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) as PCCOMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits) as KEYBOARDSTotal, 
        SUM(MOUSEUnits) as MOUSETotal, 
        SUM(PRINTERSUnits) as PRINTERSTotal, 
        SUM(MISCUnits) as MISCTotal,
        SUM(PACKAGES) as PACKAGESTotal,
        (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as LAPTOPPercentage,
        (round(SUM(PACKAGES) / SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as PACKAGEPercentage,
        SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) as PERIPHERALTotal,
        round(SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS),2) as PERIPHERALPERSALE,
        ((SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * (SUM(COMPUTERS) * 1)) * (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2))) as Ratio
    FROM my_db
    WHERE YEAR(`Created`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    AND MONTH(`Created`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY User
    ) AS lastmonth
JOIN (Select
        User,   
        SUM(COMPUTERS) as COMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) as LAPTOPCOMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) as PCCOMPUTERSTotal,
        SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits) as KEYBOARDSTotal, 
        SUM(MOUSEUnits) as MOUSETotal, 
        SUM(PRINTERSUnits) as PRINTERSTotal, 
        SUM(MISCUnits) as MISCTotal, 
        SUM(PACKAGES) as PACKAGESTotal,
        (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as LAPTOPPercentage,
        (round(SUM(PACKAGES) / SUM(PCCOMPUTERS) * 100,2)) as PACKAGEPercentage,
        SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) as PERIPHERALTotal,
        round(SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS),2) as PERIPHERALPERSALE,
        ((SUM(KEYBOARDSUnits + MOUSEUnits + PRINTERSUnits + MISCUnits) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * (SUM(COMPUTERS) * 1)) * (round(SUM(LAPTOPCOMPUTERS) / SUM(COMPUTERS) * 100,2))) as Ratio
    FROM my_db
    WHERE `Created` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 1 DAY
    GROUP BY User
    ) AS lastday
ON lastmonth.User = lastday.User
```

Answer (score 0):

First use alias for both the queries. Then run one query that subtracts those queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use individual select query for all data, now you have used only one select statement, you need to rewrite it like this - `SELECT(
Select
   num1
   FROM table1
)
 -
(
Select
  num1
FROM table2

),(
Select
   num2
   FROM table1
)
 -
(
Select
  num2
FROM table2

)`